# как при переносе с помощью InnerHTMl перенести и сопутствующий блоку event

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Пробую мысли как заставить draggable блок двигаться только в пределах блока area, решил что задать значение bounds=parent и сменить родителя ,будет отличной идеей, но не знаю как передать и логику движения этоого блока. Использую 'react-draggable'

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Block.css';
import Draggable from 'react-draggable';

class Block extends React.Component {

    handleEvent = (e, data) => {
 
        const area = document.querySelector('.area');
        
        const block = document.querySelector('.drag-box')

        const blok = document.querySelector('.block')

        area.onmouseover = function(event) {
            let target = event.target;
            target.style.background = 'pink';
            target.style.zIndex = '-1';
            block.bounds = 'body';
            area.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', blok.innerHTML)
            // blok.innerHTML = ""
            block.style.zIndex = '1000'
        }
        
        console.log(block)
        
    }

    

  render() {
    return (
        <div className='screen'>
            <div className='block'>
            <Draggable
            // bounds='parent'
                onDrag={this.handleEvent}
                onStart={this.handleEvent}
                onStop={this.handleEvent}
                onMouseDown={this.handleEvent}
                onMouseUp={this.handleEvent}
                onTouchStart={this.handleEvent}
                onTouchEnd={this.handleEvent}
            >
                <div className="drag-box">
                <textarea></textarea>
                </div>
            </Draggable>
            </div>

            <div className='area'>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Block;
```

Comment: так а зачем `innerHTML`? если ты можешь сам элемент перенести

Comment: НЕЛЬЗЯ! Очень сильно не рекомендуется, в React обращение и модификация DOM не силами React. Вы такими действиями вызываете мутацию, о которой React ничего не знает и последствия могут быть непредсказуемые. Все document.querySelector необходимо убрать...

Comment: @SwaD, так тут вроде вопрос про insertAdjacentHTML а не querySelector

Comment: @SwaD , если рендер происходит до обращения к функции тоже может поломать?

Comment: может лучше все же изучить `react-draggable` и не городить велосипедов с `insertAdjacentHTML` и тому подобным, и если вставляете код как снипет хорошо чтобы он хоть как-то да работал

Comment: насчет `поломать`, если Вы маломальски изучали реакт то знаете про виртуальное дерево компонент, так вот в данном случае у Вас будет происходить разсинхрон реального и виртуального деревьев с непредсказуемыми последсвтиями

Comment: @DaniilLoban , я примерно понимаю как работает react-draggable, но не нашел никаких способов заставить двигаться блок в пределах другого, только при попадании в него.

Comment: ну как минимум `bounds` который Вы упоминали будет правильным направлением к решению, а почему бы сразу в разметке не поместить блок в `area` ? поясните чуть больше какую задачу Вы пытаетесь решить (не в плане перетаскивания, тут все понятно) а в более общем смысле

Comment: @DaniilLoban хочу чтобы блок вносился из вне области, а потом оставался в его границах, поэтому поместить его сразу в area было бы бессмысленно.

Comment: т.е. это что-то типа `доски` на которую Вы наклеиваете `стикеры` и потом можете только менять их положение, так?

Comment: @DaniilLoban именно

Comment: @xzr1ley я обновил ответ, возможно последнее решение будет более подходящим, единственный момент который следует еще решить это положение элемента в новом родителе (`area`) должно изначально быть с некоторым смещением от (0,0) которое было при завершении `onStop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изначально я хотел сделать реализацию со сменой родительского элемента, но выяснилось что библиотека плохо отписывается от событий и в связи с этим возникает ошибка

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the
> componentWillUnmount method.
> Draggable@https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-draggable@4.4.5/build/web/react-draggable.min.js:1361:29
> react-dom.development.js:61:32

Ошибка возникает тут (в момент удаления элемента в одном месте и вставки в другом посредством условных операторов):

```
Draggable_defineProperty(Draggable_assertThisInitialized(_this), "onDragStop", function (e, coreData) {
      if (!_this.state.dragging) return false; // Short-circuit if user's callback killed it.

      var shouldContinue = _this.props.onStop(e, createDraggableData(Draggable_assertThisInitialized(_this), coreData));

      if (shouldContinue === false) return false;
      log('Draggable: onDragStop: %j', coreData);
      var newState
      /*: $Shape<DraggableState>*/
      = {
        dragging: false,
        slackX: 0,
        slackY: 0
      }; // If this is a controlled component, the result of this operation will be to
      // revert back to the old position. We expect a handler on `onDragStop`, at the least.

      var controlled = Boolean(_this.props.position);

      if (controlled) {
        var _this$props$position = _this.props.position,
            x = _this$props$position.x,
            y = _this$props$position.y;
        newState.x = x;
        newState.y = y;
      }

      _this.setState(newState); <--------  ошибка доступа к состоянию
});
```

**Обновление:**

Исследовав место ошибки я понял что функция обработчик `onStop` должна возвращать `false`, для того чтобы прервать выполнение кода до `setState`.

```
if (shouldContinue === false) return false;
```

Минус этого решения — при переносе элемент прыгает в нулевую позицию, хотя при желании я думаю это можно пофиксить через задание позиции ( `defaultPosition: {x: number, y: number}`) которую можно расчитать `x = rect.left - area-left; y = rect.top - area.top`, вот что получилось в итоге с использованием `parent`:

```js
window.useState = React.useState;
window.useEffect = React.useEffect
window.useRef = React.useRef
const {ReactDraggable: Draggable} = window

/* вычисляет находится ли прямоугольник rect внутри другого area */
const isRectInArea = (rect, area) => (
  rect.top >= area.top
  && rect.left >= area.left
  && rect.top + rect.height <= area.top + area.height   
  && rect.left + rect.width <= area.left + area.width
)

const Block = () => {
  const areaRef = useRef(null)
  const dragBlockRef = useRef(null)   
  const [transform, setTransform] = useState('none');
  const [boundsArea, setBoundsArea] = useState(false)

  const handleEvent = (e, data) => {
    /* если Draggable блок в area выходим */ 
    if (boundsArea) return true

    /* проверяем положение  Draggable блок */
    if (data && dragBlockRef &&  dragBlockRef.current && areaRef && areaRef.current) {

      const dragRC = dragBlockRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()
      const areaRC = areaRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()
      /* если  Draggable блок над area раскрашиваем ее в pink */
      if (isRectInArea(dragRC, areaRC)){
         areaRef.current.style.background = 'pink'   
      } else {
        /* иначе в голубой */
         areaRef.current.style.background = 'lightblue'   
      }
      /* в случае если драг закончен (mouseup) над area считаем что блок перемещен в area */
      if (isRectInArea(dragRC, areaRC) && e.type === 'mouseup' ){
        areaRef.current.style.background = 'lightblue'
        setBoundsArea('parent')
      } 
    }
    // необходимо вернуть false на onStop
    // так как это единственный способ избежать setState и ошибки
    // 
    if (e.type === 'mouseup') return false  
  }  

  const getDraggableBlock = () => (
    <Draggable
            bounds={boundsArea}
            onDrag={handleEvent}
            onStop={handleEvent}
        >
          <div
            ref = {dragBlockRef}
            className="drag-box">
              <textarea></textarea>
          </div>
        </Draggable>
  )

  return (
    <div className='screen'>
      <div className='block'>
        {
          !boundsArea && getDraggableBlock()
        }
      </div>
      <div 
        ref = {areaRef}
        className='area'
      >
      {
        boundsArea && getDraggableBlock()
      }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Block/>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
}
.screen {
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.block {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 250px;
}
.drag-box {
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
.area {
  position: relative;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-draggable@4.4.5/build/web/react-draggable.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Первоначальный ответ:**

Поэтому я пошел по другому пути. Храню в состоянии `boundsArea` если там `false` то ограничений нет, либо позже я задаю их (без учета прокрутки и других возможных ситуаций)

Почему можно использовать`false` видно из исходников библиотеки:

```
bounds: PropTypes.oneOfType([
  PropTypes.shape({
    left: PropTypes.number,
    right: PropTypes.number,
    top: PropTypes.number,
    bottom: PropTypes.number
  }),
  PropTypes.string,
  PropTypes.oneOf([false]) // <-------- тут
]),
```

Я написал две вспомогательные функции:

```
/* вычисляет находится ли прямоугольник rect внутри другого area */
const isRectInArea = (rect, area) => (
  rect.top >= area.top
  && rect.left >= area.left
  && rect.top + rect.height <= area.top + area.height   
  && rect.left + rect.width <= area.left + area.width
)

/* вычисляет координаты ограничения движения*/
const getBoundsArea = (rect, area) => ({
  left: area.left, 
  top: area.top, 
  right: (area.left + area.width - rect.width), 
  bottom: (area.top + area.height - rect.height)
})
```

Соответственно логика перемещения выглядит так: если мы отпускаем мышь над `area` и `Draggable` вписывается в нее мы устанавливаем ограничения перемещения `Draggable` и больше это не обрабатываем (выходим из обработчика если ограничения заданы).

Для доступа к элементам в `React` принято использовать `useRef` и свойство `current` таким образом мы не нарушаем правила доступа к элементам, т.е. не идем в обход `React` а делаем все посредством его хуков.

```js
window.useState = React.useState;
window.useEffect = React.useEffect
window.useRef = React.useRef
const {ReactDraggable: Draggable} = window

/* вычисляет находится ли прямоугольник rect внутри другого area */
const isRectInArea = (rect, area) => (
  rect.top >= area.top
  && rect.left >= area.left
  && rect.top + rect.height <= area.top + area.height   
  && rect.left + rect.width <= area.left + area.width
)

/* вычисляет координаты ограничения движения без scroll! */
const getBoundsArea = (rect, area) => ({
  left: area.left, 
  top: area.top, 
  right: (area.left + area.width - rect.width), 
  bottom: (area.top + area.height - rect.height)
}) 

const Block = () => {
  const areaRef = useRef(null)
  const dragBlockRef = useRef(null)   
  const [transform, setTransform] = useState('none');
  const [boundsArea, setBoundsArea] = useState(false)

  const handleEvent = (e, data) => {
    /* если Draggable блок в area выходим */ 
    if (boundsArea) return true

    /* проверяем положение  Draggable блок */
    if (data && dragBlockRef &&  dragBlockRef.current && areaRef && areaRef.current) {

      const dragRC = dragBlockRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()
      const areaRC = areaRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()
      /* если  Draggable блок над area раскрашиваем ее в pink */
      if (isRectInArea(dragRC, areaRC)){
         areaRef.current.style.background = 'pink'   
      } else {
        /* иначе в голубой */
         areaRef.current.style.background = 'lightblue'   
      }
      /* в случае если драг закончен (mouseup) над area считаем что блок перемещен в area */
      if (isRectInArea(dragRC, areaRC) && e.type === 'mouseup' ){
        areaRef.current.style.background = 'lightblue'
        setBoundsArea(getBoundsArea(dragRC, areaRC))
      } 
    }
  }  

  return (
    <div className='screen'>
      <div className='block'>
        <Draggable
            bounds={boundsArea}
            onDrag={handleEvent}
            onStart={handleEvent}
            onStop={handleEvent}
            onMouseDown={handleEvent}
            onMouseUp={handleEvent}
            onTouchStart={handleEvent}
            onTouchEnd={handleEvent}
        >
          <div
            ref = {dragBlockRef}
            className="drag-box">
              <textarea></textarea>
          </div>
        </Draggable>
      </div>
      <div 
        ref = {areaRef}
        className='area'
      >
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Block/>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
}
.screen {
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.block {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 250px;
}
.drag-box {
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
.area {
  position: relative;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-draggable@4.4.5/build/web/react-draggable.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Почему нужно вычислять координаты самостоятельно. К сожалению на данный момент в библиотеке существует [issue](https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-draggable/issues/677) (довольно свежий 25 дней с момента публикации) Это заметно именно в тот момент когда мы используем `parent` или `селектор элемента` для атрибута `bounds` - поведение такое что не учитывается положение элемента на странице, но ширина и высота области определяется правильно, вполне вероятно что это пофиксят, но пока этот баг присутствует. Движение `зеленого блока` ограничено областью совпадающей по размерам с `голубым блоком` но не совпадающей с ней по координатам:

```js
window.useState = React.useState;
window.useEffect = React.useEffect
window.useRef = React.useRef
const {ReactDraggable: Draggable} = window

const Block = () => {
  const areaRef = useRef(null)
  const dragBlockRef = useRef(null)   
  const [transform, setTransform] = useState('none');
  const [boundsArea, setBoundsArea] = useState(false)

  const handleEvent = (e, data) => {
    /* если Draggable блок в area выходим */ 
    if (boundsArea) return true

    /* проверяем положение  Draggable блок */
    if (data && dragBlockRef &&  dragBlockRef.current && areaRef && areaRef.current) {

      const dragRC = dragBlockRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()
      const areaRC = areaRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()
      /* если  Draggable блок над area раскрашиваем ее в pink */
      if (isRectInArea(dragRC, areaRC)){
         areaRef.current.style.background = 'pink'   
      } else {
        /* иначе в голубой */
         areaRef.current.style.background = 'lightblue'   
      }
      /* в случае если драг закончен (mouseup) над area считаем что блок перемещен в area */
      if (isRectInArea(dragRC, areaRC) && e.type === 'mouseup' ){
        areaRef.current.style.background = 'lightblue'
        setBoundsArea(getBoundsArea(dragRC, areaRC))
      } 
    }
  }  

  return (
    <div className='screen'>
      <div className='block'>
        <Draggable bounds='.area'>
          <div
            ref = {dragBlockRef}
            className="drag-box">
              <textarea></textarea>
          </div>
       </Draggable>
      </div>
      <div 
        ref = {areaRef}
        className='area'
      >
     </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Block/>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
}
.screen {
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.block {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 250px;
}
.drag-box {
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
.area {
  position: relative;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-draggable@4.4.5/build/web/react-draggable.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```